# datetime reading a different format from the real value

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I'm trying to reformat a datetime pattern on csv's files:

Original date format:

```
DAY/MONTH/YEAR
```

Expected Result:

```
YEAR/MONTH/DAY
```

`rows = df['clock_now']` is:

```
22/05/2022 12:16
22/05/2022 12:20
22/05/2022 12:21
22/05/2022 12:44
22/05/2022 12:47
22/05/2022 12:47
22/05/2022 12:51
```

Here is my complete code:

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime

filials= [
    'base.csv',
    'max.csv'
]

for filial in filials:
    df = pd.read_csv(filial)
    rows = df['clock_now']
    for row in rows:

        change_format = datetime.datetime.strptime(row, '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M')
        final_format = change_format.strftime('%Y/%m/%d %H:%M')

        df.loc[df['clock_now'] == row, 'clock_now'] = final_format
    df.to_csv(filial, index=False)
```

Returns this error saying format error in one of the values, but there is no `'2022/05/22 12:47'` value in `rows = df['clock_now']`.

```
change_format = datetime.datetime.strptime(row, '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M')
File "C:\Users\Computador\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\_strptime.py", line 568, in _strptime_datetime
    tt, fraction, gmtoff_fraction = _strptime(data_string, format)
File "C:\Users\Computador\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\_strptime.py", line 349, in _strptime

raise ValueError("time data %r does not match format %r" %

ValueError: time data '2022/05/22 12:47' does not match format '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M'
```

What am I missing out?

Comment: Format is wrong
try this
change_format = datetime.datetime.strptime(row, '%Y/%m/%d %H:%M')

Comment: `%d/%m/%Y` is `DD/MM/YYYY` format...

Comment: format should '%Y/%m/%d %H:%M'?

Comment: Hi @Dev, but the original values are not formatted this way, they are formatted as DAY/MONTH/YEAR. Shouldn't I define them like that?

Comment: Obviously not all of them are, `Ctrl+f` your CSV for `2022/05/22`

Comment: Hello friend @BeRT2me , unfortunately there are numerous different dates, from different years, control + F in this case is humanly impossible (too tiring, better said), but for quick changes it's an option really.

Comment: Well, obviously you wouldn't want to change them all, that was just meant to verify that in fact all dates are not in the same format.

Comment: Hi @BeRT2me Yes, they are in the same format, even using few values as I showed in the example, the same thing happens.

Comment: Can you try the code I have posted as an answer?

Comment: Hi @Zero The answer had not appeared, now that I refreshed the page it appeared and it worked perfectly, I will use it to find out why the error occurs in my attempt, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this,

```
dt_rows = pd.to_datetime(rows)
dt_rows = pd.Series(map(lambda dt:dt.strftime("%Y/%m/%d %H:%M"), dt_rows))
```

Output -

```
0    2022/05/22 12:20
1    2022/05/22 12:21
2    2022/05/22 12:44
3    2022/05/22 12:47
4    2022/05/22 12:47
5    2022/05/22 12:51
dtype: object
```